# VBNet 2008 Mobile: New text line in button

Tags: vb.net, mobile, button, newline, word-wrap

I've looked everywhere, I hope you can give me the final outcome ....
I made an VBNet 2008 mobile application, and I placed a large button, which should contain a text that wraps.
I tried everything, including StringBuilder object with "append", or special characters such as chr(10) & chr(13), vbCrLf, Constants.vbCrLf, \n, vbNewLine and more, and results are nothing spaces or squares when application is running!

Any solutions?

Comment: Is this winforms or a web app?

Answer (score 0):

The standard button automatically wraps - you don't need to do anything to it.[image]

Comment: In this example I write "Autowrap not work in my case". If it would work before, I would not have created this post: http://s21.postimg.org/5szjapzxv/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps for a mobile app but I've just used this for a vb.net web site

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

.. and in Page load

Button1.Text = Regex.Unescape("This is a large button with a \n lot of text to see if the text \n wraps")